# How to compare two object arrays for a filter

Tags: javascript

I would like to compare two array obj
for a filter
how to filter the array with objects strictly different from the objects of another array obj?

```js
  var y = [

     {  nb :'rouge',
        xb :'rouge',
        x  : 12 },

       { nb :'red',
         xb :'rouge',
         x  : 12 }
     ]
     ,

  var   x = [

       {  nb :'rouge',
          xb : 'rouge',
           x : 12,
       },

       {  nb :'red',
          xb : 'rouge',
          x  : 12,
       },

       {  nb :'violet',
          xb : 'violet',
          x  : 12,
        },

]

  const dispo = x.filter( x !== y );
  console.log(dispo)
```

expected result :

[ { nb : violet, 
    xb : 'violet',
    x : 12}

]

Comment: Can you explain the final purpose? Do you want to filter by object reference or by object properties? The object you wan extract can be anywhere in the array?

Comment: Why do you want an array with only 1 object inside would'nt it be better something like this: { nb : violet, xb : 'violet', x : 12}?

Comment: @jogarcia this is an example the objective is to be able to exclude in table 2 elements identical to the 1st table

Comment: @Lievno the final goal is to have an array which excludes elements identical to the other array:
! == xb &&! == nb (from table y) for example

Answer (score 1):

You will need to compare the objects by value. You can use something like lodash's _.isEqual or _.isEqualDeep. A simple approach without lodash would be something like this:

```js
function compare(a, b) 
{
  if (Object.keys(a).length !== Object.keys(b).length) {
    return false;
  }

  for (let p of Object.keys(a)) {
  
    if (!b.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
      return false;
    }
    
    if (a[p] !== b[p]) {
      return false
    }
    
  }
  
  return true;
}

function includesObj(array, obj) 
{
  for (let el of array) {
    if (compare(obj, el)) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  
  return false;
}  

console.log(x.filter(el => !includesObj(y, el)));
```

This will not do a deep comparison. It will only work if the values of your objects are primitives (not arrays, functions, other objects). But in your case it will also work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply compare two objects in javascript because the references instead of the values of this objects are compared.

You can check this link to learn about that:

https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/comparing-objects-in-javascript-ce2dc1f3de7f

If you prefer simplicity over profundity and the objects that you are putting inside de array are'nt to complex you could try Json.stringify() this transforms your object in a string making it easy to compare.

Notice that in the next example i changed the order of the array and the names for readibility.

```
var firstArray = [
  {
    nb: 'rouge',
    xb: 'rouge',
    x: 12,
  },

  {
    nb: 'red',
    xb: 'rouge',
    x: 12,
  },

  {
    nb: 'violet',
    xb: 'violet',
    x: 12,
  },
];

var secondArray = [
  {
    nb: 'rouge',
    xb: 'rouge',
    x: 12
  },

  {
    nb: 'red',
    xb: 'rouge',
    x: 12
  }
];

function difference(firstArray, secondArray) {
  return firstArray.filter(firstArrayElement => {
    return !isContainedInSecondArray(firstArrayElement, secondArray);
  });
}

function isContainedInSecondArray(firstArrayElement, secondArray) {
  return secondArray.find(secondArrayElement => {
    if (JSON.stringify(firstArrayElement) == JSON.stringify(secondArrayElement)) {
      return true;
    }
  });
}

//prints [ { nb: 'violet', xb: 'violet', x: 12 } ]
console.log(difference(firstArray, secondArray));
//prints []
console.log(difference(secondArray, firstArray));
```